# Progressbar no funciona con el celular bloqueado (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una app con un temporizador y uso una progressbar.
El problema es que al iniciar el temporizador si bloqueo el celular la progressbar se detiene hasta que vuelvo a encenderlo.
¿Como puedo hacer para que la progressbar siga funcionando con el celular bloqueado?

Comment: creo que es tema de hilos, si bloqueas el celular, el hilo principal se "duerme", entonces, por eso se detiene, podrías hacer un proceso en segundo plano para ello

Comment: Será que debe tener un procesos en segundo plano y la app necesita permisos para correr en segundo plano?